# Changing price based on option

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to change the price based on whatever is been selected from the options... I dont know if to do it using JavaScript on ajax and any how will I be able to do it please...

```
<tr>
<td width="160">Price:</td>
<td name="price"><?php echo $row['Standard_price']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

The price is selected from a database as a standard price for the item and I want it to change(NOT ON THE DATABASE) when someone select from the options below

```
<tr>
td for="length" width="160">size*:</td>
<td>
<select name="size" class="small">
<option value="£25.00">12 size</option>
<option value="£30.00">14 size(+£30.00)</option>
<option value="£40.00">18 size(+£40.00)</option>
<option value="£45.00">20 size(+£45.00)</option>
<option value="£80.00">28 size(+£80.00)</option
</select>
```

i choose 18 inch which is £40 i want it to change the price to £40 and also if i ech0

```
$length = $_POST['length'];
```

It should tell me 18 inch (+£40.00) NOT £40.00

Because on my cart it will be

```
product name: blue nike shoes
size: 18 inch (+£40.00)
Unit price: £40.00
qty:1
total price: £40.00
```

The unit price and size will change depending on what you choose from the options. please help. I have everything else working but its just getting the price to change depending on the option and also get the size you choose from the option.

If no one still understands me...
try buying a shoe from any site that sells and pick your size... although the price id the same for all sizes but in the cart it tells you want choose. 
In my case the size have different prices and i want it show on the cart what size you choose and also the price for that size.

Maybe the way i am doing it is wrong but i know it is possible to do it because i have seen it on some sites that sells items which different lengths or shapes price are different from one another.

Comment: If I understand right, when someone selects a length (let's say 14 inch), you want to get get `14 inch (+£30.00)`. Am I right?

Comment: You could simplify your life by removing the currency symbol from the value. This will save you the step of parsing a numeric value from the string before every math operation.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I'm trying to figure if what he wants is just to add the value of the option to the base price with a `+` operator.

Comment: Basically i have an item and that item comes in different sizes and each size has different prices. So when the user select the size they want, the default price will change and in the size it will tell them what size they choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

Version with an **additionnal** field :[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4rXX/5/)

Version with **original** fields   :[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4rXX/6/)

---

## with an additionnal field

I added a row to see the item size alone:

### HTML add-on

```
<tr>
  <td width="160">Item:</td>
  <td id="item">12 inch</td>
</tr>
```

### Javascript

```
function addCharge(select, elemIndex)
{
  var item = select.getElementsByTagName('option')[elemIndex];
  var price = document.getElementById('pricetag');
  var finalPrice = "";

  /* Getting the price and showing it up */
  finalPrice = parseFloat(item.text.substring(11, item.text.length-1));

  /* We set a default £25.00 value */
  if(isNaN(finalPrice)) finalPrice = "25";

  /* we add decimal */
  price.innerHTML="£"+finalPrice+".00";

  /* Getting the size and showing it up */
  var size = item.text.substring(0,7);
  var sizeDOM = document.getElementById('item');
  sizeDOM.innerHTML = size;
}
```

---

## with original fields

### Javascript

```
function addCharge(select, elemIndex)
{
  var item = select.getElementsByTagName('option')[elemIndex];
  var price = document.getElementById('pricetag');
  var finalPrice = "";

  /* Getting the price and showing it up */
  finalPrice = parseFloat(item.text.substring(11, item.text.length-1));

  /* We set a default £25.00 value */
  if(isNaN(finalPrice)) finalPrice = "25";

  /* we add decimal */
  price.innerHTML="£"+finalPrice+".00";

  /* Getting the size and showing it up */
  var size = " ("+item.text.substring(0,7)+")";
  price.innerHTML += size;
```

}

---

## *New*: With input fields

### New HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="itemPrice" name="itemPrice"/>
<input type="hidden" id="itemLength" name="itemLength"/>
```

### New JavaScript

```
var itemPriceDOM = document.getElementById('itemPrice');
var itemLengthDOM = document.getElementById('itemLength');

/* we add decimal */
itemPriceDOM.value = finalPrice;

/* Getting the size and showing it up */
var size = item.text.substring(0,7);
itemLengthDOM.value = size;
price.innerHTML += " ("+size+")";
```

See the new [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4rXX/13/) !

Comment: Ghilied if you echo length you will the whatever that in the value i dont want to show whats in the value but ..inch (+£..) because on the admin or staff end they wouldnt be able to tell what size show it was

Comment: Also if they select an item that is +£45 the £25.00 should change to £45 because default price for 12 inch is £25 and 14 inch is £30.

Comment: Okay I get it, so the price in parenthesis is the default price for each item. Maybe should you add a "description" field in your database for each cart item (that is filled by the item specs: size, length, whatever you want), this way the staff could know the ID of the item and its specific size. I'm working on something, watch my future update in a few minutes.

Comment: @Ian Take a look at my answer (it only contains new stuff, I deleted all the old content it had).

Comment: Ghillied thanks but i can't seems to be able to pass the pricetag and size to cart.php even though i have added name="pricetage" and name="size"

Comment: @Ian: It's because the fields are not `input`(s), I made an update at the END of this actual answer, take a look at it please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement something like this:

```
<tr>
   <td width="160">Price:</td>
   <td id="priceContainer"><?php echo $row['Standard_price']; ?></td>
</tr>

<select name="title" id="priceDropDown" class="small">
  <option<?php fillSelect('size','','',true); ?> DISABLED value="">Select size</option>
  <option<?php fillSelect('size','12'); ?> value="25">12 size(+£25.00)</option>
  <option<?php fillSelect('size','14'); ?> value="25">14 size(+£30.00)</option>

</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#priceDropDown').on('change', function() {
          //$('#priceContainer').text($(this).val());
          $('#priceContainer').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
   });
});
</script>
```

In this example I'm using jQuery.

Comment: thanks not what i wanted I want it to change the price but when it echo i want it to echo 12 size(+£25.00) not 25 because I am going to post 12 size(+£25.00 to the cart

Comment: Take a look at my last edit :). Is that what you were looking for ?

Comment: thats not what I was looking for.... basically I want the prices t change as it drop down but when i $title= $_POST['title']; I want to post for example 12 size(+£25.00 not the value 25. If that makes senses

Comment: Probably I'm not understanding you right, but you can set the option value attribute to "12 size(+£25.00)", wrap the select in a form and add the following attribute to the select tag: onchange="$(this).parent().submit()".

Comment: I personally recommend using something like `<?= getSelectValue('size','','',true); ?>` (or `<?php echo getSelectValue('size','','',true); ?>` if you do not have short tags support) as a way to separate concerns. Your `fillValue()` (renamed here to `getSelectValue()` to describe what it does) is unnecessarily printing data, while it could simply return it (and this way it could be used outside the templates).

Comment: @Ian: Just remove "`value="25"`" from this code and the browser will send the content of the `<option>` tag instead. The server will receive exactly the same as the user sees.

Comment: try buying a shoe from any site that sells and pick your size... although the price id the same for all sizes but in the cart it tells you want choose. 
In my case the size have different prices and i want it show on the cart what size you choose and also the price for that size.